# decimal to ip address

Tags: c, winapi

I have made use of winapi function inet_ntoa to convert the unsigned long decimal number to ip address .I'm getting the ip address in reverse .I used the website  http://www.allredroster.com/iptodec.htm to get the decimal equivalent of the input ip address.

```
for ex decimal equivalent of 206.117.16.66 is 3463778370
```

and if i use the function inet_ntoa to get back the ip its giving the ip as **66.16.117.206**.Below is the code for the same , please let me know the correct way to do it.

```
  #include<stdio.h>
  #include<WinSock2.h>
  #pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")

  int main()
  {

       ULONG ipdec=0;
       struct in_addr ipadr;
       char ip[50];
       printf("\n Enter the ip address in decimal equivalent of ip address : ");
       scanf_s("%ld",&ipdec);
   ipadr.S_un.S_addr=ipdec;
       strcpy_s(ip,inet_ntoa(ipadr));
   printf("\n The ip address in dotted format is :  %s \n" ,ip);

  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`inet_ntoa` is specified as taking its input in network byte order.  You are providing the input in host byte order, which on x86 systems is backward (little endian vs. big endian).   You need to pass the decimal address through `htonl` first.

Comment: Brilliant answer by each one of you  ,thanks for clearing the concept .+1 upvote for each one .Thanks .

Answer (score 3):

```
206 = 11001110
117 = 01110101
16  = 00010000
66  = 01000010



(11001110 01110101 00010000 01000010) = 3463778370
```

Convert to binary. But them together and convert to Decimal.

Comment: @jayaram : i know the conversion from decimal to ip and vice versa,but wanted to know the winapi function which does the correct conversion.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`htonl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738556%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (stands for host to network long) to convert ip address from host byte order to network byte order. It works for both little-endian and big-endian machines.

```
ULONG ipnet = htol(ipdec)
```